# Lexicosemantic and lexicosyntactic?

Tags: syntax, lexical-semantics

I am reading a paper that distinguishes between lexicosemantic patterns and lexicosyntactic patterns ([page 4, paragraph 2](http://people.few.eur.nl/frasincar/papers/DeRiVE2011/derive2011.pdf)). I am unfamiliar with these terms and am having trouble understanding what they mean from context/Google. Can someone explain the difference between the two with clear examples?

Answer (score 2):

Lexicosyntactic patterns are strings of words paired with syntactic structures; they depend only on the syntactic categories of the component words, with no reference to their meaning.

Lexicosemantic patterns are strings of words paired with semantic categories.

So, a lexicosyntactic pattern might be something like "[John: Noun + Subject] [kicked: Verb] [the: Determiner] [ball: Noun + Direct Object]", while a lexicosemantic pattern might be something like "[John: Name] [kicked: Active Verb] [the: Definite] [ball: Toy]".